# CSS content substring function

Tags: html, css, regex

The `content` property along with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements offer a handy way of creating small and useful details like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/u5zec8w6/), where I generate dotted, book-styled list of journal contents.

There are functions like `attr()` or `counter()` to insert dynamically generated content. Currently, this requires placing the actual content in a separate attribute, what often causes duplication (like when I want the `content` to hold a node's `innerHTML` value) so my code looks like this

```
<a data-page="148" href="/archive/70/2/148"></a>
```

Is there a way I could eliminate `data-page` attribute, by parsing it out of `href`? It would be cool to have something like this in CSS:

```
content: substr(attr(href), lastIndexOf(attr(href), '/'));
```

or even better with regex:

```
content: match(attr(href), /\d+$/);
```

Comment: Restructure your website so that the `href` is `148` then use `attr(href)`  :P

Comment: @divinecomedian, hmm, that's an option, although seem like to much hassle for a minor detail

Comment: You can't use JavaScript?

Comment: I can, I was just curious about most straightforward solution. Maybe CSS4 has something cooking in the specs

Comment: There is no way to further process an attribute value referenced by `content` (see [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/generate.html#content)). The best you can have is to concatenate data from different attributes.

Comment: @DivineComedian I'd strongly advise against structuring your website according to the needs of styling or visual presentation. This might save you a couple of bytes but opens a can or worms wrt maintainability and extensibility. Rather define an onload handler to iterate over all `a` elements synthesizing the data attribute from `src`, or define an onclick handler to compose a target link from a `src` prefix and the data attribute.

Comment: @collapsar Yeah, it was a joke...

Comment: @DivineComedian Yes, I should have read more carefully. Sorry. Feeling sort of dumb right now ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

As you note, CSS is not (currently) sufficiently sophisticated to dynamically extract substrings from attributes.

Nevertheless, javascript will enable you to eliminate the `data-page` attribute from your anchors, so they simply read:

```
<a href="/archive/70/2/148">
```

Additionally, the following CSS:

```
h4>a {
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

will, (along with a few other tweaks here and there), allow you to skip hard-coding the ellipsis as `::after` content.

See example below:

```js
var pageHref = [];
var pageNumber = [];

function assignPageNumbers() {
    var pages = document.querySelectorAll("h4>a");

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        pageHref[i] = pages[i].getAttribute("href");
        pageNumber[i] = pageHref[i].substr((pageHref[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1));
        document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("h4:nth-of-type(" + (i + 1) + ")>a::after {content: '" + pageNumber[i] + "'}", 0);
        }
    }

window.addEventListener('load',assignPageNumbers,false);
```

```css
body {
width: 500px;
}

h4 {
position: relative;
}

h4>a {
color: black;
display: block;
font: 16px sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

h4>a span {
position: relative;
background:#fff;
top: 4px;
padding-right: 2px;
}

h4>a:after {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-top: 4px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
text-decoration: none;
}

h4>a:hover {
color: slategray;
border-bottom: 1px dotted slategray;
}
```

```html
<h4>
    <a href="/archive/70/2/144">
        <span>A short title</span>
    </a>
</h4>
<h4>
    <a href="/archive/70/2/148">
        <span>Very long and incredibly verbose title that should, at the very least, span several lines or more to demonstrate wrapping</span>
    </a>
</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks, your example indeed looks very nice for this particular scenario. The reason I hard-coded ellipsis is because it conforms to rules of text styling like, size, color, etc, while `border-bottom` needs to be styled separately

Comment: No problem. You can always use identical `CSS` styles to those you posted above and simply edit one line of javascript so that it reads (instead): `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("h4:nth-of-type(" + (i + 1) + ")>a::after {content: '....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................." + pageNumber[i] + "'}", 0);`